# How to annotate nested dictionary in python 3.6?

Tags: python, annotations, python-3.6, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'SCOPES': {
        'read': 'Read scope',
        'write': 'Write scope',
        'userinfo': 'Access to user info',
        'full-userinfo': 'Access to full user info',
    },
    'DEFAULT_SCOPES': {
        'userinfo'
    },
    'ALLOWED_REDIRECT_URI_SCHEMES': ['http', 'https', 'rutube'],
    'PKCE_REQUIRED': import_string('tools.oauth2.is_pkce_required'),
    'OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS': 'oauth2.validator.OAuth2WithJwtValidator',
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS": 3600,
}
```

And I want to annotate the following key with integer type to check that it's always integer:

```
'REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
```

as Integer. In python 3.6 we don't have TypedDict. What may I replace it with?

Comment: When you say annotate, what exactly are you annotating and how is it different?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of dictionaries object types are preserved. You can set the type of the value inside of the dictionary (as this value is actually its own object with its own type).

In your example, you can set the type of the value as an int with:

```py
OAUTH2_PROVIDER['REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS']=int(
    OAUTH2_PROVIDER['REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS']
)

print(type(OAUTH2_PROVIDER['REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS'])) #=> <class 'int'>
```

EDIT:
Getting to OP's core issue of removing nested if statements [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/models.py#L627):

You can simply add a single if statement that forces a int class or raises an error:

```
REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS = oauth2_settings.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS
if not isinstance(REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS, int):
    REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS = timedelta(seconds=REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS)
else:
    e = "REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS must be an int"
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(e)
refresh_expire_at = now - REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS
```

Comment: and what if I'll write 'REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': "hello",

Comment: In this case, you would overwrite the object type with a string. I get the feeling you are reffering to a specific use case. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do (the bigger picture item)?

Comment: I want to eliminate nested if statements here in my version of the function (I don't need expired access_tokens for refresh_tokens to be deleted): https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/models.py#L627 and hardcode only integer type in seconds

Comment: Added an edit that allows you to remove the timedelta check looking instead for an int object and raising an error otherwise. This hits your hardcoded int nail on the head.

Comment: But anyway, how can I use, let's say, typing.Dict to annotate types for this dict?

Comment: You might consider creating a class based object and enforcing variable types using the methods available to you there. Then you can call this object similar to the way you are calling this dictionary.